# RRDTool legend label placement

Tags: linux, bash, rrdtool

My titles in the right column are in the wrong place. Can anyone help me to correct?

```
rrdtool graph ... \
COMMENT:'   ' \  
"LINE1:kliensek#0000FF:Csatlakozott kliensek száma" \  
COMMENT:'           ' \  
"LINE2:aktivkliensek#99FF00:Aktív kliensek száma" \  
COMMENT:"\n" \  
GPRINT:kliensek:LAST:"    Legutóbbi\:%7.0lf%s" \  
COMMENT:"                    " \  
GPRINT:aktivkliensek:LAST:"Legutóbbi\:%7.0lf%s\n" \  
GPRINT:kliensek:MIN:"     Minimum\:%9.0lf%s" \  
COMMENT:"             " \  
GPRINT:kliensek:MIN:"     Minimum\:%9.0lf%s\n" \  
GPRINT:kliensek:MAX:"     Maximum\:%9.0lf%s" \  
GPRINT:aktivkliensek:MAX:"Maximum\:%9.0lf%s"
```

I can't position the last title in the right column to the left.

```
GPRINT:aktivkliensek:MAX:"Maximum\:%9.0lf%s"
```

Also in the right column, the first title

```
PRINT:kliensek:LAST:"     Legutóbbi\:%7.0lf%s"
```

is at the wrong place by 1 pixel. The minimum title only is OK.

Comment: You said you figured it out --- what was it? I have precisely the same problem (see http://www.cowlark.com/graphs/img_netstat.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to try:

1. Add a newline (\n) at the end of your last line.
2. Remove the space from the beginning of your second "Minimum" label.
3. You have a line: COMMENT:' ' between the two LAST and two MIN statements;  add that between your two MAX statements too (or get rid of it altogether)
4. Not related to the formatting - You have two entries for "kliensek:MIN" - is that intentional?

So you should have:

```
GPRINT:kliensek:LAST:" Legutóbbi\:%7.0lf%s" \
COMMENT:" " \
GPRINT:aktivkliensek:LAST:"Legutóbbi\:%7.0lf%s\n" \
GPRINT:kliensek:MIN:" Minimum\:%9.0lf%s" \
COMMENT:" " \
GPRINT:aktivkliensek:MIN:"Minimum\:%9.0lf%s\n" \
GPRINT:kliensek:MAX:" Maximum\:%9.0lf%s" \
COMMENT:" " \
GPRINT:aktivkliensek:MAX:"Maximum\:%9.0lf%s\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use tabs and maybe switch to a more tabular presentation

```
                avg      min     max
   Line A        22       10      24
   Line B        23        8      30
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Everything is OK now, I got answer on your mailing list. Thank you Tobi for the help. ;)

Comment: Can I ask how you get the colum headers?

Comment: use the COMMENT:... statement